# Nginx rewrite a URL with two variables

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, rackspace-cloud

I have been trying to solve this for sometime now.

This is my setup

```
/www/index.php
/www/page.php
```

I want some SEO urls on:

```
/www/page.php?pageId=45&catId=34
```

My NGINX rewrite is

```
location / {
rewrite ^/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)$ /page.php?pageId=$1&catId=$2; 
}
```

The URL however if tried, `site.com/1/23` - fires a 404. Can someone help? Can I also redirect to that URL in case someone ever tries page.php directly..

Comment: You regex doesn't match numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex `A-Za-z` only match alphabet both uppercase and lowercase. For matching with number *too*, you should use adding `0-9` in above regex, i.e.

```
rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /page.php?pageId=$1&catId=$2;
```

For demo and explanation, click [this regex101 page](http://regex101.com/r/zZ0aV7/1).